# How to change the code according to the particular Button click?

Tags: javascript

There r 2 buttons RED and BLUE.
If click on RED some 'sample code' has to come and moving to BLUE 'sample code has to hide and 'New paragraph' has to come and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd add onClick listeners. You could do these easy enough with JQuery.

Something like...

```
$.('#myRedbutton').click(function(){
  //Do the red button stuff.
};

$.('#myBluebutton').click(function(){
  //Do the blue button stuff.
};
```

For [pure Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) you could edit the HTML of the button like so..

```
 <button onclick="redButton()">Red</button>
```

Clicking the above button would invoke `redButton()`.

Comment: I want this by using Javascript.

Comment: @Sonu Well, JQuery is Javascript but I'll edit my question.. one moment.

Comment: Okay Thank u. But i want it by basic javascript

Comment: use onclick attribute is a bad practice

Comment: @Ethan There's no advantages to your approach over mine. Using Pure Javascript for this in general is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var red = document.getElementById('RED');
var blue = document.getELementById('BLUE');
var sampleCode = document.getElementById('SAMPLE');

red.addEventListener('click', function () {
    blue.style.display = 'none'; // hide blue, and you can use this method to hide every element you want
    sampleCode.style.display = 'block'; // display sampleCode element
};
```

Comment: function showStuff(id) {
 var span = document.getElementById(id);
 if(span.style.display == 'none')
 {
  span.style.display = 'block';
 }
 else
 {
  span.innerHTML = hideStuff(id);
 } 
 }

Comment: function hideStuff(id) {
 var span = document.getElementById(id);
 if(span.style.display == 'none')
 {
  span.style.display = 'block';
 }
 else
 {
  span.innerHTML = showStuff(id);
 } 
 
 }

Comment: <input type="button" value="Red" onclick="showStuff('answer1');">
<input type="button" value="Blue" onclick="hideStuff('answer2');"/>
<span id="answer1" style="display: none;"><p style="color:#FF3333"> HAI </p></span>
<span id="answer2" style="display: none;"><p style="color:#6600FF"> H R U </p></span>